# M4S file extensin in Streaming video. How to download and use in Python

Tags: python, video-streaming

I was watching a movie on hotstar and decided to download that movie. I will use Python to do that. But for that I need the video URL. I inspected the page and came to know that it has segmented streaming file.

[image]

The requested URL that I have highlighted in the picture is:

https://hses1.hotstar.com/videos/movies/bengali/sweater/1260011260/1569583501995/ad1f5bdbac36f489da1adb7f077be226/video/avc1/3/seg-1306.m4s

It has a .m4s extension. How to read that file? Or how to work with it using Python?

Comment: m4s is the same as fragmented mp4

Answer (score 0):

USE IDM to download movie, or you can scrape bit there must be m3u8 link as well which might be not in use as of now